# (dNj/dt) = Nj(fj - (C/K)Φ(t))

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to solve the following differential equation for N(t) hours now, could anyone provide me with some help?

[image]

Comment: Why create a new question instead of editing the previous one?

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide much information about the individual terms meaning, so I will just try to solve it as classical calculus problem. Further I assume that $j$ is excluded in the sum over $i$. Then one possible solution is:

Divide by $N_j$ to get
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{N_j} \frac{dN_j}{dt} = f_j - \frac{C}{K} \phi \ .
\end{align*}
Note that $\frac{d}{dt} \ln(N_j) = \frac{1}{N_j} \frac{dN_j}{dt}$ and Integrate both sides then we have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^t \frac{d}{dt} \ln(N_j) \ dt = \int_0^t f_j - \frac{C}{K} \phi \  dt \ .
\end{align*}
For the integral on the left hand side we have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^t \frac{d}{dt} \ln(N_j) \ dt = \ln(N_j(t)) - \ln(N_j(0)) = \ln\left(\frac{N_j(t)}{N_j(0)}\right) \ .
\end{align*}
Then by letting this back in the equation above and taking the exponential we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{N_j(t)}{N_j(0)} = \exp\left( \int_0^t f_j - \frac{C}{K} \phi \  dt \right) \ .
\end{align*}
Then multiply by $N_j(0)$ to get
\begin{align*}
N_j(t) = N_j(0) \exp\left( \int_0^t f_j - \frac{C}{K} \phi \  dt \right) 
\end{align*}
and we have a solution.